# How to fix the problem of drop-down menus being transparent and not readable in Kubuntu 15.10

Tags: kubuntu, 15.10, kde, menu, transparency

**The Problem:** The task manager dropdown menus are all transparent and not readable at all. The same goes for all the dropdown menus of libre office. I have tried to change the desktop theme but the transparency kept on appearing on all those menus hindering me from reading them. Disabling all the effects of the desktop (ALT + Shift + F12) did not help at all as well.

**Objective:** I need to remove all the opacity and transparency of those menus. I simply need a clear readable desktop environment.

Any suggestions, comments or solutions will be greatly appreciated.

**Note:** I am using Kubuntu 15.10 (Not a fresh installation. I have just installed the KDE desktop environment on top of the Ubuntu Mate 15.10 then decided to use it as my default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Head to

```
System Settings > Workspace Theme > Desktop Theme > Theme
```

Choose style you like, `Oxygen` seems to be darkest

[image]

Comment: +1 - After trying your suggestion and restarting the session, everything seems to work well with this dark theme. Thank you for your fast reply.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the Application Colour Scheme in: <kbd>Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Appearance</kbd> -> <kbd>Colour</kbd>.

Change the Theme with a Darker one and see how it goes. My menus were white and my theme dark so no menus were visible when I click on a drop-down menu.

[image]